# How to add custom login title instead of "customer login" in Magento?

Tags: authentication, default, page-title, magento-1.6

I'm using magento 1.6.1.0 for our e commerce store. Only the problem is client asking to remove "customer login" from login page. How can i remove the magento default page title from every page. Pls anybody knows the solution for this pls pinging your answer..

Thankyou for advance..

Best Regards..

Answer (score 3):

Open this file **app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Block/Form/Login.php**,
Find "_prepareLayout()" function.
Comment Out the "setTitle" command.

So your code now will look like this.

```
    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        //$this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setTitle(Mage::helper('customer')->__('Customer Login'));
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To modify the customer login page you can edit the template file. Try `app/design/frontend/default/default/customer/form/login.phtml` or whichever theme you are using.